# orphanRemoval=true removes all related entities

Tags: doctrine, api-platform.com, symfony3.x

I have a strange problem with a relation between two entities:
One Joboffer can have many jobofferLocations, while Many jobOfferlocations only have one joboffer:

```
class Joboffer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_joboffer", type="integer", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"api_read", "api_write"})
     */
    protected $id;
/**

     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Joboffer\JobofferLocation", mappedBy="joboffer",  orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     * @Groups({"api_read", "api_write"})
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    protected $jobofferLocations;


....
/**
     * @param JobofferLocation $jobofferLocation
     */
    public function addJobofferLocation(JobofferLocation $jobofferLocation)
    {
        if ($this->jobofferLocations->contains($jobofferLocation)) {
            return;
        }
        $this->jobofferLocations->add($jobofferLocation);
        $jobofferLocation->setJoboffer($this);
    }
```

The jobofferlocationclass:

```
class JobofferLocation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_joboffer_location", type="integer", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"api_read"})
     */
    protected $id;

/**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJoboffer()
    {
        return $this->joboffer;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $joboffer
     */
    public function setJoboffer($joboffer)
    {
        $this->joboffer = $joboffer;
    }
```

On Updates I have this problem:
When I use "orphanRemoval=true,", it removes all jobofferlocation entities, when I don't use it, but "cascade=remove", it doesn't remove the ones that aren't in the relations any more.
So, is there a way to update all relations? (Remove the ones that aren't needed any more, adding new ones and updating existing ones.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer:

first of all, the methods addJObofferLocation and removeJobofferLocation are needed and orphanRemoval must be set to true.
The trick seems to be in adding the right (not double) locations.

```
  class Joboffer
  {
     ...       

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Joboffer\JobofferLocation", mappedBy="joboffer", orphanRemoval=true,cascade={"persist"})
     * @Groups({"api_read", "api_write"})
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    protected $jobofferLocations;
   /**
     * @param JobofferLocation $jobofferLocation
     */
    public function addJobofferLocation(JobofferLocation $jobofferLocation)
    {

    if ($this->jobofferLocations->contains($jobofferLocation)) {
        return;
    }

    /** @var JobofferLocation $location */
    foreach ($this->jobofferLocations as $location){

        //check if this location exists
        // it seems we need this, because of the API plattform bundle
        if ($location->getIdLocation() == $jobofferLocation->getIdLocation()){
            // if it exists, just copy the new jobofferlocation settings

            return;
        }
    }
    $jobofferLocation->setJoboffer($this);
    $this->jobofferLocations->add($jobofferLocation);

}

public function removeJobOfferLocation(JobofferLocation $jobofferLocation)
{
    if (!$this->jobofferLocations->contains($jobofferLocation)) {
        return;
    }
    $this->jobofferLocations->removeElement($jobofferLocation);
    $jobofferLocation->removeJobOffer();
}
```